# Messed with my /etc/profile and now an error pops up every time I log in

Tags: command-line, bash, 16.04, .profile, etc

I am fairly new to Ubuntu, and did a little more messing around than I should have. I was reading a guide on downloading the Oracle 8 JDK and it said to change the last few lines of the /etc/profile file. It popped up with an error after I did this and now I can't figure out how to change it back.

> bash: /etc/profile: line 25: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
>   bash: /etc/profile: line 25:`fi'

That is the error that pops up. This is what the /etc/profile file looks like:

```
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).

if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ "$BASH" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
fi

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/BIN:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH
```

I don't know how to read this or how to fix it and I was stupid for trying to edit it in the first place, without knowing what I'm doing, but any advice on how to fix it would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `for` conditional construct ends in `done`, which is missing in your case.

Check the `^^^^` mark below:

```bsh
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done  
  ^^^^  
fi
```

Comment: Seems were both were pretty quick with this one :)

Answer (score 5):

The part here:

```
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
fi
```

has to look like this:

```
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
fi
```

Comment: It worked, thank you! Does everything else look good, then. So that I can leave it alone until I know what I'm doing, without any errors?

Comment: Looks legit so far I can see :) you should mark the answer of heemayl as correct one by ticking the checkmark beside his answer and maybe give me an up vote, his answer is more into detail what was wrong.

Comment: I tried, it wouldn't let me vote because my account is so new. I do appreciate the response, though. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on my system a few days ago after I installed JVE1.8 and JDK1.8. Make sure the `#` symbols in front of `/etc/profile`(line 1) and `and Bourne`(line 2) are present as well as the `done` in between the `fi` commands at the end are present.

If after that, it still gives an error, try adding `unset i` above the `done` command.

If it still gives an error, try adding `unset i` above the `done` command.

```
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).

if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ "$BASH" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/BIN:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH
    fi
done
fi
```